# ng-options - substitute $scope with vm

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following working code:

```
<select ng-model="setPriceClass" 
    ng-options="price as price.label for price in priceClass">
</select>

function ExampleCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.priceClass = [
      {'label': 'label1', 'value': '1'},
      {'label': 'label2', 'value': '2'},
      {'label': 'label3', 'value': '3'},
      {'label': 'label4', 'value': '4'}
    ];
    $scope.setPriceClass = $scope.priceClass[0];

}
```

In ng-route: ExampleCtrl as example

My priceClass object is displayed in the select field.
Now I want to use "vm." instead of "$scope." but can't get it to display the priceClass in my select field.

Tried the following:

```
<select ng-model="example.setPriceClass" 
    ng-options="price as example.price.label for price in example.priceClass">
</select>

function ExampleCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.priceClass = [
      {'label': 'label1', 'value': '1'},
      {'label': 'label2', 'value': '2'},
      {'label': 'label3', 'value': '3'},
      {'label': 'label4', 'value': '4'}
    ];
    vm.setPriceClass = vm.priceClass[0];

}
```

How to set the ng-options right?

Comment: `example.price.label` is wrong, only part that needs `example` is the array reference for `in` at end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify route configuration by adding [`controllerAs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) property:

```
.when('/prices', {
    templateUrl: 'path/example.html',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'example'
})
```

Then in template:

```
<select ng-model="example.setPriceClass" 
    ng-options="price as price.label for price in example.priceClass">
</select>
```